# Please check if the sentence I am presenting correctly describes the situation I am presenting

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

I would like to summarize the following algorithm in one sentence.

Algorithm:

1. Let i=1.
2. Suppose node i is a source node.
3. Obtain the reward accordingly, denoted by R_i.
4. Repeat 2) to 3) for i=2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 100.
5. By comparing R_1, R_2, ..., R_100, choose which node is the optimal source node.

For the above algorithm, I summarize as follows:

> Also, the algorithm is based on a scheme of comparing all cases in which every node is selected as a source node and then choosing the best case.

Is the above statement correctly describing the algorithm above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think so.

> The algorithm selects a node which has an associated reward that is greater than or equal to the reward associated with any other node.

Or more concisely

> > The algorithm selects a node with an associated reward greater than or equal to any other.

The ideas that each node has an associated reward and that selection is based on the maximum reward are entirely lost in your proposed sentence.